# Как сгенерировать файл со случайными значениями в том числе и не целыми

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа, генерация-случайных-данных

Как сгенерировать файл со случайными значениями в том числе и не целыми на питоне. Буду рада любой помощи и совету ;)

Comment: У вас здесь как минимум два вопроса. Что именно не получается?  Сгенерировать случайные значения? Запись их в файл? Что вы уже пытались сделать?

Comment: Есть функция [random.uniform(a, b)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.uniform), которая генерирует равномерно распределенные случайные числа с плавающей точкой в диапазоне от a до b.

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import random
from random import randint

num = []
for _ in range(10):
    value = randint(0, 10)
    print(value)
    num.append(value)

num_1 = []
for _ in range(10):
    value = random()
    print(value)
    num_1.append(value)

for i in num:
    open('random_num.txt', 'a').write(str(i) + '\n')

for i in num_1:
    open('random_num.txt', 'a').write(str(i) + '\n')
```